# How to animate change of background from one point

Tags: android

I have an Button in my activity. When I click on it, I want the background color of the activity to change from the point where I clicked to the whole activity. It should change as a circular animation that starts at the point where I touched the screen and expands until it fills the screen.  Any way of doing this?

Comment: yes: read about `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Material Animation library](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations),

[image]

**This is the default Enter Animation**

What is happening step by step is:

Shared orange box is transitioning from MainActivity to DetailsActivity.
DetailsActivity background viewgroup visibility starts as INVISIBLE.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundViewGroup"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        ...
```

After SharedElementEnterTransition ends a CircularReveal animation takes place making the background viewgroup visible.

```
Transition enterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
    enterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            animateRevealShow(bgViewGroup);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {}
    });
```